# Is this matrix a Linear Transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider $T:P_2 (\Bbb R) \rightarrow M_{2x2} (\Bbb R)$ , defined by:

$T(a+bx+cx^2) = \begin{bmatrix}a+b & a-c\\b+c & 0\end{bmatrix}$

a) Prove that T is a linear transformation.

I know that for linear transformations: $T(cx+y) = cT(x)+T(y)$ *how do I use it?*

b) Find a basis for the null space of T and the range of T.

I don't know how to find basis', I just know that they span a vector space and for the sake of helping me understand null space, explain it as you would to someone who doesn't know what it is.

Thanks StackExchange!

Answer (score 0):

The key to this problem is to identify these vector spaces with $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$. On the left, the polynomials of degree $2$ form a three dimensional vector space and so we may visualize there vectors as taking the form $p = \left(\begin{matrix}a\\b\\c\end{matrix}\right)$. Meanwhile the space $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is four dimensional so we write $M = \left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\\z\\w\end{matrix}\right)$ say. Then this transformation looks more like

$$ T(p) = T\left(\begin{matrix}a\\b\\c\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}a+b\\b-c\\a-c\\0\end{matrix}\right) = a\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\\1\\0\end{matrix}\right) +b\left(\begin{matrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right)+c\left(\begin{matrix}0\\-1\\-1\\0\end{matrix}\right).$$

This interpretation allows us to visualize and rewrite the transformation as the matrix equation

$$\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 1& 0 \\0 & 1& -1\\1& 0 & -1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}a\\b\\c\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}a+b\\b-c\\a-c\\0\end{matrix}\right).$$

So yes this is a linear transformation (although you could have verified this without the matrix formulation).

Now, assuming that you are comfortable finding the null space and column space of a matrix, we find that the null space is $\{0\}$ and the column space is linear span of the first three standard basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Converting this back to the original spaces of polynomials and $2\times 2$ matrices that is Null$(T) = \{0\}\leq P_2[\mathbb{R}]$ and Col$(T) = span\left\{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right),\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right),\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)\right\}\leq M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Edit: I have just noticed that you are not comfortable with the concept of null space. Briefly, to find the null space of a matrix means to solve the equation $Ax = 0$ which can be done by row reducing the *augmented matrix* $(A|0)$. Before learning about such things as the null space and column space, you have surely already had plenty of practise with the process of Gaussian elimination (a.k.a row-row-row reduce gently down the page, merrily merrily merrily merrily, life is but a dream).

Comment: There’s no need to augment a matrix to find its null space (kernel). Notice that row operations have no effect on the additional $0$ column, so it’s just extra baggage.

Comment: I am aware of that and only included the additional information for the benefit of the distressed question asker.